# Consuming JSON dates in a EXTJs gridpanel

Tags: c#, extjs

I have a object that im serializing to a JSON object using JSON.Net. This object is then being consumed by a JSON Store which is attached to a ExtJs GridPanel.

All fields except date fields render fine , the only way i can render date fields is if i use text columns. But then i get the following /Date(1293746400000+0200)/ rendered as text which is useless.

I know i need to convert that somehow to a proper date object but i have not idea how atm.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.Net has various date/time converters to help you deal with this.  See [this blog post](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx) for some details.  So you could use the `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter` for example, then eval the result into a JS date object.  I can't recall off the top of my head how an Ext store will deal with that, but maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks all i needed to do was changed the convertor to JavaScriptDateTimeConverter and it woked correctly , i obviously had to made the columns 'datecolumn' and set the datatype to date.

Answer (score 7):

"M$" in the preceeding example is misleading, its "MS".  Here is a clear example that works in extjs 4.  The 'LastFellOffCliff' field is set to be a date with incoming format in the Microsoft JSON date style:  "/Date(...)/"

```
Ext.define('ACME.model.CoyoteModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
                { name: 'CoyoteID', type: 'int' },
                'Nickname',
                { name: 'LastFellOffCliff', type: 'date',  dateFormat: 'MS'  },
                'Notes'
            ]

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [here](http://encosia.com/2009/04/27/how-i-handle-json-dates-returned-by-aspnet-ajax/).

In most cases you can pass your own formatted string (i use "yyyy-MM-dd" in my projects as i don't need time) and re-use it on the other side (format it as a valid date constructor).

Answer (score 0):

In the field(s) that is/are for the date in your JsonStore, you can set the field's type to 'date' and its dateFormat to 'M$'. Works like a champ.